# Alternating sum of integers in Python using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I need to write a simple function in Python that calculates the alternating sum of a list of integers.

Example:  [ a1, a2, a3, ...] will be [a1 - a2 + a3 - a4...]

I need to use a lambda function to implement this.

So far I have

```
print reduce(lambda a,b : ((-a) + b), [10, 20, 30, 40])
```

which prints out 20; but it should print -20.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: 1. -10 + 20 = 10 | 2. -10 + 30 = 20 | 3. -20 + 40 = 20 | So i think you are getting write answer as per your logic so its kind of symentic error

Comment: so what I actually want is 10 - 20 = -10 | 30 - 40 = -10 | -10 + - 10 = -20

But when I try 

`print reduce(lambda a,b : (a + (-b)), [10, 20, 30, 40])`

I get -80, it's very weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your lambda function, `reduce` works like this:

```
def myReduce(f, L):
    arg1 = L[0]
    for arg2 in L[1:]:
        arg1 = f(arg1, arg2)
    return arg1
```

As you can see, this will negate the running total every time:

In the first iteration, it computes `-10 + 20 = 10`, which then gets stored as `arg1`. Then, your lambda is called with the arguments `10` and `30`, which makes it compute `-10 + 30 = 20`; so now `arg1` takes the value `20`. Finally, the lambda is called with `20` and `40`, which makes it compute `-20 + 40 = 20`.
See the problem?

There are several ways by which you can solve this. Here are a few:

```
L = [10, 20, 30, 40]
sum(map(lambda t : t[0]-t[1], zip(L[::2], L[1::2])))
```

Or

```
answer = 0
for i,elem in enumerate(L):
    mult = [1,-1][i%2]
    answer += elem * mult
```

Or

```
mults = itertools.cycle([1,-1])
answer = 0
for elem, mult in zip(L, mults):
    answer += elem, mult
```

Comment: Ahh i completely understand now, looking up the reference to the reduce built-in-function it did not make a reference to the fact that it wont hold on to the running total. But this explains why it was working the way it is. Your solutions all work as expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to include the cycle in a lambda like this

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> reduce(lambda a, b, c=cycle((-1, 1)) : a + next(c) * b, [10, 20, 30, 40])
-20
```

The trick here is that `reduce` only passes values to `a` and `b`. `c` is assigned the cycle just once when the function is created